# Send post-tags to wordpress within XML-RPC

Tags: c#, xml-rpc

I use XML-RPC.net 3 and joeblog dll in C#. Everything is OK, but I cant create and send post-tags to WordPress. 
I can create posts with categories, title, excerpt, content, cutomfields but no success to create post-tags.
Its my code:

```
 public void createPost(newPost np)
        {
            loginformobject = new LoginForm();
            string postid;
            icp = (IcreatePost)XmlRpcProxyGen.Create(typeof(IcreatePost));
            clientProtocol = (XmlRpcClientProtocol)icp;
            clientProtocol.Url = url.Text;
            try
            {
                postid = icp.NewPost(1, User.Text, Pass.Text, np, 1);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("createPost ERROR ->" + ex.Message);
            }
        }

 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            customField newCustomField2 = default(customField);

            newCustomField2.key = "Testttttttttttt";

            newCustomField2.value = "testttvalye";



            newPost newBlogPost = default(newPost);
            newBlogPost.title = "Some Title<AliReza Test>";
            newBlogPost.description = "Some description Test Test Test Test<AliReza Test>";
            newBlogPost.custom_fields = new customField[] { newCustomField2 };
            newBlogPost.categories = new string[] { "Test" };
            newBlogPost.mt_excerpt = "Tozihate Kotah";
            newBlogPost.mt_taxonomy = new string[] { "test","test2" };
            createPost(newBlogPost);
        }
```

How can send post with tags within XML-RPC in C#?

Is there any library or code to create post-tags?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fix to this

```
 public string[] categories;
    public string title;
    public string description;
    public string mt_excerpt;
    public customField[] custom_fields;
    public string[] mt_keywords;
```

and

```
newBlogPost.mt_keywords = new string []{ "t1","t2"};
```